# Regular expression to match everything up to string

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to match everything up to the last "Saving*" line before "ModelFinish". I can almost do this with negative look-around (described in [Regular expression to match a line that doesn't contain a word](https://stackoverflow.com/a/406408/11918892)), but can't get it working with newlines in the string I'm trying to match. I'm using notepad++ and there's a checkbox for ". matches newline"

**Input:**

```
Begin: model 17
Epoch 15800, loss 4051304.017, val_PMAE 6.9
Saving at epoch 15828 with loss: 3974847.290
Saving at epoch 15889 with loss: 3968749.471
ModelFinish: Stop training
Begin: model 18
Saving at epoch 15889 with loss: 3968749.223
Saving at epoch 15889 with loss: 3968749.200
Epoch 15800, loss 4051304.017
ModelFinish: Stop training
Begin: model 19
```

**Desired first match:**

```
Begin: model 17
Epoch 15800, loss 4051304.017, val_PMAE 6.9
Saving at epoch 15828 with loss: 3974847.290
```

**Desired second match:**

```
Begin: model 18
Saving at epoch 15889 with loss: 3968749.223
```

**My attempt** (with ". matches newline" checked):

```
^Begin:(?:(?!Saving.*Model).)*$
```

My plan is to use notepad++ to find-and-replace the text I don't want with "", so that I'm just left with the final "loss" from each model. (Ie: model 17 loss: 3968749.471, model 18 loss: 3968749.200, etc)

Comment: To get until the last line before ModelFinish you could use https://regex101.com/r/c3RnbS/1 but your desired result only matches the first line after  Begin or Epoch To get those matches you could use https://regex101.com/r/NJckKI/1

Comment: How about: `^Begin:(?:(?!ModelFinish).)*(?=^Saving)`?

Comment: You desired matches are not in line with the requirements, they show you want to match until the first line starting with `Saving` before `ModelFinish`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - the desired matches as written are correct (it just so happens that in the two examples 'everything up to the last "Saving*" line before "ModelFinish"' is equivalent to 'the first line starting with Saving before ModelFinish'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to enable the dot matching the newline if you match the newlines using `\R` to match a unicode newline sequence.

To match before the last occurrence of *Saving* before *ModelFinish* you could match the lines that don't start with ModelFinish and use positive lookahead `(?=` that asserts what follows is a newline and Saving.

```
^Begin:.*(?:\R(?!ModelFinish).*)*(?=\RSaving)
```

- `^` Start of string
- `Begin:.*` Match `Begin:` and any char except a newline 0+ times
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `\R(?!ModelFinish)` Match a newline and assert that the line does not start with ModelFinish
  - `.*` Match any char except a newline 0+ times
- `)*` Close non capturing group and repeat 0+ times
- `(?=\RSaving)` Positive lookahead, assert what is on the right is a newline followed by Saving

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2p6Qr5/1)

Comment: Neither of these is quite right. The requirement is to match everything up to the last "Saving*" line before "ModelFinish"

Comment: @maurera Do you mean like this? `^Begin:.*(?:\R(?!ModelFinish).*)*(?=\RSaving)` https://regex101.com/r/2p6Qr5/1

Comment: @maurera I have updated the answer with an explanation.